# error when Select item from Datagridview | access database-visual basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

i have an error when click on a item from datagridview to load all informaation for this item in some Text Boxes ,
my code is :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick    
    otherdata()
    End Sub 
 Sub otherdata()
    Try
        If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0) Then Return
        FlatTextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        FlatTextBox2.Text = String.Empty
        FlatTextBox3.Text = String.Empty
        FlatTextBox4.Text = String.Empty
        Dim id As Integer = DataGridView1(1, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT items.ClientName, items.ClientAddress, items.ClientPhone, items.ClientCredit, items.ClientLastPay FROM items where items.ClientID = {0}", id))
        FlatTextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
        FlatTextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        FlatTextBox3.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
        FlatTextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString
        dt.Dispose()
        dt = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try    
End Sub
```

the error is a messagebox said ; **Index was out limits. It cannot be negative and must be smaller than the size of the collection. No parameter : index**

Comment: Try : <= 0  A DataGridView contains -1 row before columns are added.

Comment: how can i did that ? give me an example !

Comment: If (DataGridView1.Rows.Count <= 0) Then Return

Comment: thanks work perfect :)

Comment: i have the same problem :( look to my source code `http://up.dev-point.com/download279606.html` i hope you help me .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the assignments of FlatTextBoxX with a if statement:

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then 
        FlatTextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
        FlatTextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
        FlatTextBox3.Text = dt.Rows(0)(2).ToString
        FlatTextBox4.Text = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString
End If
```

Comment: @barbou if it helps, would you please mark as answer?

Comment: i have the same problem :( look to my source code `http://up.dev-point.com/download279606.html` i hope you help me .thanks

Comment: by debugging the error is in this line `Dim id As String = DataGridView1(2, DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value.ToString`